# How can I convert IMPORTXML data in Google Sheets to a Date value for the purpose of conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, xml-import

I have set up a simple Goolge Sheet that uses IMPORTXML to extract timestamp data using this XPath

```
/html/body/section/article/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]
```

for article URLs from this website (https://earlygame.com/). With this formula

```
=IMPORTXML(B2,$K$2)
```

it is able to take the URL in B2 and will produce a result that looks like this: `"October 6th 2023, 17:22 GMT+2"`.

The date is accurate but Google Sheets doesn't recognize the date as an actual date value and so I can't do any conditional formatting (Ideally I want to put something like, if older than 1 month highlight red etc.)

I get this error "parameter '17:22 GMT+2 ' cannot be parsed to date/time." So i tried to remove time and timezone with this formula

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(C2, 1, FIND(",", C2) - 1))
```

so that it would only use the date, but then i got "DATEVALUE parameter ' October 6th 2023' cannot be parsed to date/time".

Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REGEXREPLACE` to remove the parts of the string that make it an invalid date.

Note that this also removes the information about the time and the timezone.

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"st|nd|th|,.+",)
```

[image]